# Does Haxe support static generic fields?

Tags: generics, static, haxe

I am 100% new to Haxe and I cannot figure out how to make static generic field work -- so I am wondering now if it is supported in the first place.

Consider the code:

```
@:generic
class Main<T> {
  var instGen:T;
  static var statNonGen:String;
  @:generic // is it OK?
  static var gen:T; // error
}
```

Instance generic field works, static non-generic field works, however static generic field ends up with odd error message "Type not found : T".

Thank you in advance for clarification what I do wrong.

Comment: T is the type of the instance of the class, which statics don't have. You can give static functions their own generic, though.
`static function test<S>(param:S):Void
`

Comment: @MSGhero, so the answer is "no" :-) Thank you -- could you post it as regular answer instead of comment, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the comments:

No. T is the type of the instance of the class, which statics don't have. You can give static functions their own generic, though.

`static function test<S>(param:S):Void`